бывало + present tense
This is from РОССІЯ И ЕВРЕИ 1924:

Когда мы, бывало, говоримъ русскому правительству, что то или
другое ограниченіе ведётъ только къ отчужденію евреевъ или
опредѣлённыхъ еврейскихъ группъ, напримѣръ, недопускавшейся въ учебныя
заведенія молодёжи, отъ государства, то въ этомъ была своя
относительная правда, ибо дѣйствія и той стороны могли, конечно,
оказать вліяніе на результатъ

I was expecting бывало to have a past habitual meaning ("used to X"), but here it is used with the present tense. Can someone explain the syntax?

Бывало does express the habituality in the past, but it can and does modify verbs in what grammatically are the present and the future tenses, probably even more often than not:


Бывало, окликнешь ее: " Кукла, Кукла! " Она остановится и смотрит долгим, удивленным лошадиным взглядом. [Фазиль Искандер. Лошадь дяди Кязыма (1966)]
Я там гостил каждое лето.  Бывало, скачу вихрем на коне.  Черкеска, газыри, кинжал, — удалая голова. [А. Н. Толстой. Черная пятница (1924)]
Ей, конечно, уже надоели чужие квартиры, вечная спешка, она, бывало, покрикивала на него, злилась, краснела. [Анатолий Азольский. Лопушок // «Новый Мир», 1998]


Note that when used with the present or with the future, бывало only amplifies the sense of habituality that was already there. Verbs in what grammatically is the present or the future can describe habitual actions in the past even without бывало:


Крикну, а в ответ — тишина // Снова я осталась одна [Александр Алов, Алла Пугачёва. "Сильная женщина" // 1993]
Всю жизнь с чемоданом в зубах. Только устроимся — перевод.  Поехали. [Борис Екимов. Предполагаем жить // «Новый мир», 2008]




but here it is used with the present tense

Such use is not specific to "бывало". It's just an example of Historical Present. Present tense could've been used here even without "бывало", it just wouldn't had that habitual meaning (as described by Quassnoi).

No, it's not the h̶i̶s̶t̶o̶r̶i̶c̶a̶l̶ p̶r̶e̶s̶e̶n̶t̶ historic present. The historic present is where the present tense is used with past-tense meaning, not where a past-tense adverb is used to give the present tense a habitual present meaning.
